# Async Compute on User interaction

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a standard web page with Ajax update panel. WorkFlow of the page is : The user can add some entity, delete some entity(on click of their respective buttons) to create some definition. And then user can save these definition, edit it and delete it.

Upon adding/deleting the entities, a complex calculation needs to take place which would be time intensive. What I want is, when the user adds or deletes some entity, a separate thread should do the computation and update the UI. The point to be kept in mind here is, when the entity are added or deleted , the corresponding server side code need to be run first, which adds/deletes the entities from a collection stored in session(that means I can not launch a ajax call on the button, because the server side code for the button needs to run first), and then the logic for computation.

What I have thought of doing is
1. Make the server call for button click
2. When response returns, use AJAX client life cycle to catch the response before page is rendered. This is the place where I would make ajax call, if request was for add/delete entity.

This how ever seems over complicated. I am sure, there must be a easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out answer to my problem. What I needed was PageAsyncTask which is in built in asp.net for these kind of jobs.

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=Page.RegisterA&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=page.registerasynctask#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=PageAsyncTask&oq=PageAsyncTask&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.12...1041870.1041870.1.1043226.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.V7_pOwd4QVU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3369bfeac41cfa6a&biw=1680&bih=880)